# Why are my sentiment analysis coefficients so weird?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, sentiment-analysis, coefficients

I'm doing a simple sentiment analysis logistic regression classifier with 'sad' and 'happy' as my labels. The 'text' column is a list of text messages.

My features are (1) number of sad and happy words taken from two .txt files with these words (2) negation - not counting happy words two places after a "not" as happy (3) same negation but with 'sad' label (4) Count vectorizer (5) tf-idf vectorizer.

I've done the same task in a class before and the vectorizers had the highest coefficient/weight in the final log-reg algorithm's classification report. we found out that our features were of little to no use and vectorization is the strongest feature definition method.

In my current task, I'm seeing the exact opposite - why? Is something wrong with my code thats making the coeffs of the vectorization look odd? Below is the code (not including the non-vectorization features).

```
#Count Vectorization#

cv=CountVectorizer()
cv.fit_transform(datatrain['cleantext'].values)
cv_datatrain=cv.transform(datatrain['cleantext'].values)
lr = LogisticRegression()
y_train=datatrain['label']
lr.fit(cv_datatrain,y_train)
y_pred=lr.predict(cv_datatrain)
y_pred_list=y_pred.tolist()
new_pred_list=[]
for x in y_pred_list:
    if x == 'happy':
        new_pred_list.append(1)
    else:
        new_pred_list.append(0)

datatrain['predicted_by_countvector']=new_pred_list

   
# TF-IDF # 

import nltk.corpus 
nltk.download('stopwords') # need to import nltk.corpus of stopwords for it to work in the tfidf function # 
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=300, min_df=5, max_df=0.7, stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))
x = datatrain['cleantext']
y = datatrain['label']
x = tfidf.fit_transform(x)
tf_datatrain = tfidf.transform(datatrain['cleantext'].values)
clf = LinearSVC()
clf.fit(tf_datatrain,y_train)
y_pred_tf = clf.predict(tf_datatrain)
y_pred_tf_list = y_pred_tf.tolist()
new_pred_tf_list=[]
for x in y_pred_tf_list:
    if x == 'happy':
        new_pred_tf_list.append(1)
    else:
        new_pred_tf_list.append(0)

datatrain['predicted_by_tfidf']=new_pred_tf_list

print(confusion_matrix(y,y_pred_tf))
print(classification_report(y,y_pred_tf))
print(accuracy_score(y, y_pred_tf))
print(f1_score(y, y_pred_tf, average=None))


########## algorithm - logistical regression ##########
model = LogisticRegression()
X = datatrain[['n_happy_words', 'n_sad_words','negation_happy','negation_sad','predicted_by_countvector', 'predicted_by_tfidf']]
y = datatrain['label']
model = model.fit(X, y)
datatrain['predicted_by_logistic_regression'] = model.predict(X)

log_odds = np.exp(model.coef_[0])
pd.DataFrame(log_odds, 
             X.columns, 
             columns=['coef'])\
            .sort_values(by='coef', ascending=False)

######### Training error analysis ##########
print(pd.crosstab(datatrain['label'], datatrain['predicted_by_logistic_regression']))
SK_accuracy=accuracy_score(y,datatrain['predicted_by_logistic_regression'])
print(f'Accuracy: {SK_accuracy}')
precision=precision_score(y,datatrain['predicted_by_logistic_regression'], average='binary', pos_label='happy')
recall=recall_score(y,datatrain['predicted_by_logistic_regression'], average='binary', pos_label='happy')
print(f'Precision: {precision}')
print(f'Recall: {recall}\n')

print (pd.DataFrame(log_odds, 
             X.columns, 
             columns=['coef'])\
            .sort_values(by='coef', ascending=False))
```

Here is my result:

```
Training Data Results...:
predicted_by_logistic_regression  happy   sad
label                                        
happy                              4117   126
sad                                 115  5348
Accuracy: 0.9751699979394189
Precision: 0.9728260869565217
Recall: 0.9703040301673345

                              coef
negation_happy            1.793558
n_sad_words               1.403265
negation_sad              1.025126
n_happy_words             0.745600
predicted_by_tfidf        0.532705
predicted_by_countvector  0.001277
```

Comment: same data on both? same classifier?

Comment: Do you mean same dataframe? yes, the data is from the same .csv file for all. And I'm using the log-reg classifier as shown above.